babel.config and ts.config for alias import
I have tried to config alias import for React Native project for shorter import path, but I have some problem is the babel.config is not work and the tsconfig is not match either.


Here is my project structure:



Here is my babel.config.js


Here is my tsconfig.json



Thank you for your help.
